# How to use custom widget and uic.loadUi without importing custom widget class package?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

Using PyQt4's [uic.loadUi](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#PyQt4.uic.loadUi), I’d like to load a .ui file and use a custom widget in it. This means using the third `package` argument of `uic.loadUi` which will import the package with the custom widget's class inside.

However, I wish to define the custom widget's class in the same file as where I'm calling `uic.loadUi`. I’m trying to achieve this like so:

```
class MyCustomClass(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    """ This is my custom class for my custom widget """
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtWidgets.QPushButton.__init__(self, *args)

...

sys.modules['mycustompackage'] = MyCustomClass
uic.loadUi('my_ui.ui', self, 'mycustompackage')  # Loads .ui file which contains the MyCustomWidget widget
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'MyCustomClass' has no attribute 'MyCustomWidget'
```

**Is there anything I could do to make this actually work?** I suspect that `MyCustomClass` isn't defined in the manner `uic.loadUi` expects it.

In Qt Designer, I've promoted `MyCustomWidget`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="MyCustomWidget" name="customWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>50</x>
      <y>70</y>
      <width>113</width>
      <height>32</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>MyCustomWidget</class>
   <extends>QPushButton</extends>
   <header>MyCustomClass</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

---

## Solution

I solved it using the above .ui file like this:

```
class MyCustomClasses(object):
    class MyCustomWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
        def __init__(self, *args):
            QtWidgets.QPushButton.__init__(self, *args)

...

sys.modules['MyCustomClasses'] = MyCustomClasses
uic.loadUi('my_ui.ui', self)  # Loads .ui file which contains MyCustomWidget
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote from the documentation you linked to, the third argument of `loadUi` is:

> the optional package that is the **base package** for any **relative imports** of custom widgets [emphasis added]

The actual module name that the custom class will be imported from must be specified in the `ui` file itself. In Qt Designer, this is achieved by setting the "Header file" to the appropriate value, and it will be stored in the `<header>` tags inside the `ui` file. Note that this value can be the fully qualified package path of the module (e.g. "pkg.mymodule") - in which case, it would not be necessary to use the third argument of `loadUi`. There should never be any need for `sys.module` hacks.

The `loadUi` function is quite simple. It just generates a python module in exactly the same way that the command-line tool does, and then loads it using `exec`.

Answer (score 1):

The are three possible ways.
For example, you have the module *QtCustomWidgets.widgets.mybutton*
It is a files *QtCustomWidgets/widgets/mybutton.py* and *QtCustomWidgets/python/mybuttonplugin.py* in you project with *MyButton* class in it.

**First way** define *includeFile* method from  *QtCustomWidgets/python/mybuttonplugin.py* as:

```
def includeFile(self):
    return "QtCustomWidgets.widgets.mybutton"
```

**Second way** is to use uic.loadUi with packadge path:
    uic.loadUi('my_ui.ui', self, packadge='QtCustomWidgets.widgets')

but you have to use the dot in you module names (*includeFile* is the method from  *QtCustomWidgets/python/mybuttonplugin.py* ):

```
def includeFile(self):
    return ".mybutton"
```

, so in the header it must look like this:

```
<customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>MyButton</class>
   <extends>QPushButton</extends>
   <header>.mybutton</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
```

And result way still will be **"QtCustomWidgets.widgets" + ".mybutton"**

There is the source PyQt code custom widget loader (*qobjectcreator.py*), you may find it yourself:

```
class _CustomWidgetLoader(object):
    def __init__(self, package):
        # should it stay this way?
        if '.' not in sys.path:
            sys.path.append('.')

        self._widgets = {}
        self._modules = {}
        self._package = package

    def addCustomWidget(self, widgetClass, baseClass, module):
        assert widgetClass not in self._widgets
        self._widgets[widgetClass] = module

    def search(self, cls):
        module_name = self._widgets.get(cls)
        if module_name is None:
            return None

        module = self._modules.get(module_name)
        if module is None:
            if module_name.startswith('.'):
                if self._package == '':
                    raise ImportError(
                            "relative import of %s without base package specified" % module_name)

                if self._package.startswith('.'):
                    raise ImportError(
                            "base package %s is relative" % self._package)

                mname = self._package + module_name
            else:
                mname = module_name

            try:
                module = __import__(mname, {}, {}, (cls,))
            except ValueError:
                # Raise a more helpful exception.
                raise ImportError("unable to import module %s" % mname)

            self._modules[module_name] = module

        return getattr(module, cls)
```

**Third way:**
To add path to your widgets in sys.path (you have to be import sys):

```
sys.path.append( "./QtCustomWidgets/widgets" )
uic.loadUi('my_ui.ui', self)
```